# Hyperparameters optimization using GridSearch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras, grid-search

So I have been trying to optimize my keras model's parameters using Grid search and for most parts it works just fine but whenever I am trying to optimize each layer's parameters the model just hangs. I was wondering if someone could look into it and tell me what's happening or if there is something I am doing wrong.

```
def create_model(dense_layers=2,
             dense_size_1=6,
             dense_size_2=7,
             init_mode_1='uniform',
             init_mode_2='uniform',
             gd='adam',
             transfer_1='relu', transfer_2='relu'):
    K.clear_session()
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(0, dense_layers+1):
        if i == 1:
            model.add(Dense(dense_size_1,input_dim=8,activation=transfer_1, kernel_initializer=init_mode_1))
        if i == 2:
            model.add(Dense(dense_size_2, activation=transfer_2, kernel_initializer=init_mode_2))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=gd, metrics= ['accuracy'])
return model


model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

dense_size_1 = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
dense_size_2 = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
init_mode_1 = ['uniform', 'lecun_uniform', 'normal', 'zero', 'glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform']
init_mode_2 = ['uniform', 'lecun_uniform', 'normal', 'zero', 'glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform']
gd = ['adam', 'sgd']
transfer_1 = ['relu', 'tanh']
transfer_2 = ['relu', 'tanh']

param_grid = dict(dense_size_1=dense_size_1, dense_size_2=dense_size_2,
                  init_mode_1=init_mode_1, init_mode_2=init_mode_2,
                  transfer_1=transfer_1, transfer_2=transfer_2)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1

grid_result = grid.fit(X, y)
```

It perfectly works good and fine if I just use parameters like hidden neurons for each layer, optimizer, epochs and batch size but it hangs if I make it more complex like separate activation function for neurons in each hidden layer or separate kernel initializer for neurons in each hidden layer.

What could be possibly going wrong in this?

Comment: Check your system-memory during execution and remember: *model just hangs* is not a very technical description.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how else I can explain the technicality of "Hang". It just stops. The terminal is not updating as it does when I try other parameters (which i described above). If I do not try to optimize the complexity of each neuron it is "Working fine" else "it hangs".

Comment: Please first try with `n_jobs=1`. It seems an issue when doing with parallel (multi-thread) processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use talos in place for gridsearch. Please find the code below:

```
### p contains the dictionary of parameter to be tuned ###
p = {'first_neuron': [4, 8, 12, 24, 48,64],
    'second_neuron': [4, 8, 12, 24, 48,64],
    'third_neuron': [4, 8, 12, 24, 48,64],
    'activation': ['relu'],
   'batch_size': [1000, 2000, 7000]
}
# add input parameters to the function #########################
def outage(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, params):
    # replace the hyperparameter inputs with references to params dictionary ##
    model = Sequential()
    ### Input layer 
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation=params['activation']))
    ### Introducing 3 hidden layers 
    model.add(Dense(params['first_neuron'], activation=params['activation']))
    model.add(Dense(params['second_neuron'], activation=params['activation']))
    model.add(Dense(params['third_neuron'], activation=params['activation']))
    ### Output layer with activation = linear (default)
    model.add(Dense(1))
    ### Defining loss function, optimizer and accuracy 
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    ### make sure history object is returned by model.fit() 
    out = model.fit(x=x_train, 
                y=y_train,
                validation_data=[x_val, y_val],
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=params['batch_size'],
                verbose= False)
    #### return the output model 
    return out, model

### Talos hyperparameter 
t = talos.Scan(x=x_train, y=y_train, 
          params=p, model=outage, experiment_name='neural')
```

Refer to the link for

- [more detail on how to use](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/neural-network-and-hyperparameter-optimization-using-talos/)
- [more details on Talos](https://github.com/autonomio/talos)